# Converting all pages of a multi page PDF into an image with PHP causes a duplicate result in the image

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick

So I am using imagick to convert a PDF into an image.  All works well for single page PDFs but I ran into a snag with a multi page pdf.

I found an example on how to deal with multiple pages here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-appendimages.php so I took that code:

```
$im = new Imagick($src);
    $im->readImage($src);
    $im->resetIterator();

    $ima = $im->appendImages(true);
    $ima->setImageFormat('jpg');

    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    print $ima;
```

This works in that it produces an image with each page of the pdf the problem is that the PDF is displayed twice in the image.  So, a three page PDF is displayed as a single image of 6 pages.

[Here is an example PDF](http://www.reljac.com/so_1/Document1.pdf)
and the [resulting image](http://www.reljac.com/so_1/test.jpg) created with the above code.

What am I doing that is causing this to happen?

---

**Resolution**:

Based on tandu's answer this did the trick

```
$im = new Imagick($src);
    $im->resetIterator();

    $ima = $im->appendImages(true);
    $ima->setImageFormat('jpg');

    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    print $ima;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Imagick` constructor loads the image from the file you provide.  When you run `readImage()`, it loads them again.  You only need one of those two.